IGV GenArk assembly error
I am simply trying to follow the documentation here: https://igv.org/doc/igvjs/#Reference-Genome/ and test UCSC GenArk assembly GCA_000002305.1 with the following code (tracks removed to avoid complexity)
import React, { createRef, Component } from "react";

const igvStyle = {
  fontFamily:
    "open sans,helveticaneue,helvetica neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",
  paddingTop: "60px",
  margin: "5px",
};

class IGVViewer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.container = createRef(null);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Load igv.js dynamically from a CDN
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/igv@2.9.4/dist/igv.min.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => {
      const { geneData } = this.props;

      // Extract chromosome, start, and end from geneData
      let chromosome = geneData?.chromosomes?.[0] || "NC_051843.1"; // Default chromosome for testing
      const start =
        geneData?.annotations?.[0]?.genomic_locations?.[0]?.genomic_range
          ?.begin || 100000;
      const end =
        geneData?.annotations?.[0]?.genomic_locations?.[0]?.genomic_range
          ?.end || 200000;

      // IGV Options, using GenArk genome reference
      const igvOptions = {
        genome: "GCA_000002305.1", // Replace with any valid GenArk genome ID
        locus: `${chromosome}:${start}-${end}`, // Set locus dynamically from geneData
        tracks: [], // No tracks for now, can add later
      };

      // Log the full IGV options object to verify URLs and locus
      console.log("IGV Options:", igvOptions);

      // Initialize IGV browser
      window.igv
        .createBrowser(this.container.current, igvOptions)
        .then((browser) => {
          console.log("IGV Viewer successfully loaded.");
          // Log the initialized IGV browser to verify further
          console.log(browser);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error loading IGV:", error);
        });
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="igv-div" ref={this.container} style={igvStyle}></div>;
  }
}

export default IGVViewer;

but I get Unknown genome id: GCA_000002305.1 and I am not sure why.

Can you say anything about where this code came from? I followed the tutorial link and didn't see an obvious source. One thing I'll say is that your chromosome NC_051843.1 is a dog chromosome and your genome assembly GCA_000002305.1 is horse. I would not expect that gene to be in that assembly, but I honestly have no idea whether it even got far enough for that to be the issue because I am not used to querying IGV in this fashion. Maybe first try your example in the browser and ensure it works?
